# rendering multiple partials in div on link click in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to coding. 
I'm trying to find a solution on how I can render multiple partials in the same DIV on separate link click.

So far I can render one partial in the div(partial 1), but I'm stuck on how to render other partials when other links are clicked.

This is my code so far

in `views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb`I have

```
   <li>
        <%= link_to user_path(current_user), :remote => true do %>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Partial1
        <% end %>

   </li>
    <li>
        <%= link_to user_path(current_user), :remote => true do %>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></i> Partial2                
        <% end %>
    </li>
```

In the `users_controller.rb`I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

   def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      @user_partial1 = @user.1partials
      @user_partial2 = @user.2partials

       respond_to do |format|
        format.html { @user_partial1 }
        format.js { render :show }
       end
    end   
end
```

In the `users/show.html.erb`I have

`<div id="usercontent"></div>` were the partials should render.

in the  `view/users/show.js.erb` there is this code

`$("#usercontent").html("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>"shared/partial1")%>");`

This code works fine to render only one partial in one div but I can't figure out how to render the other partials in the `#usercontent`div when associated link is clicked.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: you can use `@user_partial1.each do |partial| .....` in your file `view/users/show.js.erb`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter along with your `link_ to`

```
 <li>
    <%= link_to user_path(current_user,partial: '1'), :remote => true do %>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Partial1
    <% end %>
```

```
    <li>
    <%= link_to user_path(current_user,partial: '2'), :remote => true do %>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></i> Partial2                
    <% end %>
</li>
```

In your controller you can get the value of partial to render:

```
@partial_to_render = params[:partial]
```

And in `view/users/show.js.erb`

```
$("#usercontent").html("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>"shared/partial" + @partial_to_render)%>");
```

If you need to append the content to the existing html in `#usercontent` div use Jquery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of $("#usercontent").html().

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I followed the approach of Kumar Abhinav. The only additional thing you need is to specify the partial in the routes. Such as:

```
get "/show/:partial", to:"users#show"
```

Now you can trigger multiple partial.